# How to create a task in SBT that calls a method?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am new developing tasks in `SBT` and I'm trying to figure out how to create a task that integrate my existing code.

In my code I have a singleton object that has `run` method that requires several parameters

```
object MyObject {
    def run( param1: String, param2: Int, param3: String, ...) = {}
}
```

My question is: **How can I define a Task in `SBT` that calls my `run` method specifying all its parameters in my `build.sbt` file?**

I can imagine something like this in `build.sbt`

```
lazy val myTask: TaskKey[Seq[File]] = taskKey[Seq[File]]("My task")
lazy val myTaskRun = (sourceManaged, dependencyClasspath in Compile, runner in Compile, streams) map { (dir, cp, r, s) =>
    val param1 = ...
    val param2 = ...
    val param3 = ...
    val paramN = ....
    MyObject.run( param1, param2, param3, ...)
    Seq(file("path"))
  }
```

Comment: If object is a part of your build you may just call it as you've written. The file should reside in `project` directory

Answer (score 1):

**1. You can use `fullRunInputTask` for that.**

In your build.sbt

```
lazy val example  = InputKey[Unit]("example", "Run something.")

fullRunInputTask( example, Compile, "somefun.CallMe")
```

Under `src/main/scala/somefun/CallMe.scala`

```
package somefun

object CallMe {
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    println("Params are: " + args.mkString(", "))
  }
}
```

To call your task use `example`, e.g. "example 1 2 3"

**2. You can create your own InputTask**

[see InputTask in SBT Doc](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Input-Tasks.html)

Creating a custom `InputTask` allows a flexible input parser (with suggestions on tab), allows linking with other tasks. It simple integrates better into SBT.